# changing permissions of ldd from 755 to non-executable and security rationale

Tags: permissions, security

My system is Novell SLES 11.4 x86-64.

I was presented with:

> The ldd command must be disabled unless it protects against the
>   execution of untrusted files.

If you google the above you can easily obtain more information about it.

The `oem` setting of `/usr/bin/ldd`  is  `root.root` with permissions 0755.

It was also stated "An acceptable method of disabling 'ldd' is changing its mode to 0000"

If I do this and disable `ldd` completely then my system does not work. The first ramification I immediately found was YAST doesn't work.

So the first compromise was to do `chmod 644 /usr/bin/ldd`
while leaving the file owned by `root.root`.  This still causes problems and errors when running legitimate software (where a lot of money is spent on licensing).

So I have since concluded this request is either antiquated or just bad.

Looking for thoughts & suggestions, thanks.

Comment: I think that if you wanna go the secure way, chown -x -ing your `ldd` ain't quite the way to go. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of this advice before, and it's just plain wrong.

On Linux, `ldd` is typically a bash script and ends up doing the equivalent of

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 your_program
```

So `ldd` doesn't actually execute "any" program itself, but calls the binary loader and *that* tries to run your program.

(The rest of the script is basically a wrapper to work out the correct `ld.so` to call; eg 32bit, 64bit, etc).

Removing permissions from `ldd` has zero security gains on Linux.

Comment: The script had a known vulnerability in the past, so the advice used to be valid for distributions which hadn't fixed that...

Comment: Note that the CVE is "disputed".  All it does is stop people who don't realize that `ldd` could effectively be the same as executing a file.  Indeed on other OS'es (eg Solaris) it _does_ execute the file specifically.  This CVE is a "band aid" along the lines of "don't put `.` on your PATH".

Comment: Yes, indeed; I should have qualified that (it's valid if you consider the STIG rules to be valid). In any case, since SLES applied the fix for the CVE, the point is moot...

Answer (score 3):

This refers to [CVE-2009-5064](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-5064), which is [fixed in SLES](https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=677787) since 11 SP1. So you should be covered by the “it protects against the execution of untrusted files” clause. You can find more information on the vulnerability and a proof-of-concept [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ldd-arbitrary-code-execution/).